# Error while saving table in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Run some queries and got the results! Wanted to save the results into Big Query dataset but kept getting an error!

> To copy a table, the destination and source datasets must be in the same region. Copy an entire dataset to move data between regions.

However, other people in the team are able to save the results to the same dataset.
Can't save it as view also because the query is too complex for Big Query to run!
Would appreciate it if someone could help me with this error.
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSphj.png)

Comment: Did you read the error message? Can you provide more information about this specific problem and what you already tried to solve it? Take a look in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: hey! i have added the error on top! you can click on the 'click here for image'! 

But this is the error that i get: To copy a table, the destination and source datasets must be in the same region. Copy an entire dataset to move data between regions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to store query results as a table you need to have both your data set and your query execution in the same region.

To check your **data set** region open your data set and look for "Data location" (note that you cannot change the region of your data set once it has been created).

To check your **query** region got to MORE > Query settings and look for "Data location".

That said, it looks like this is a bug on Google's end. See this discussion on [googlecloudcommunity.com](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Location-error-on-BigQuery/m-p/424261): Even if both the data set and the query are in the same region BigQuery currently throws this error. It seems like this error has been introduced very recently (this week).

What you can do is put a CREATE statement at the beginning of your query, like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_dataset.my_table`;
CREATE TABLE `my_dataset.my_table` AS SELECT ....
```

Alternatively you can go to the query settings and "Set a destination table for query results".

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all. Wherever it is that your query is running at and you're trying to export from is in a different region from the dataset you specified to export to and it's not able to do that.

I would instead suggest exporting the results to a file (e.g. Google Drive) via another option on the "Save Results" list and importing those results back into a table in your own dataset (which, according to the error message, lives in a different region).

Comment: Thanks for this! is it possible to change the region where the query is running? I checked all my tables and views but they are all set in US. Another user tried to run it and she managed to create the table

Will need to create tables in Big Query to link it to Data Studio!

Comment: Yes you can change the region where the query is running. Just go to MORE > Query settings. But also check out my Answer - it may be that you're running into a BigQuery bug that you can circumvent as described in my Answer.